# How to display the correct data in their respective text inputs?

Tags: php

I am having trouble displaying the SessionName, SessionDate and SessionTime in their respective text inputs. What should happen is that the user is suppose to select a Session (Assessment) from the drop down menu. Now when they submit the drop down menu, the details of the Session which are SessionName, SessionDate and SessionTime, should be displayed in their text inputs. But instead I am recieving undefined variable errors which are these below:

> Notice: Undefined variable: dbSessionName in ...on line 243
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: dbSessionDate in ... on line 244
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: dbSessionTime in ... on line 245

How can I get the SessionName, SessionTime and SessionDate to be displayed in their respective text inputs?

Below is the code:

```
$sessionquery = "
SELECT SessionId, SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId
FROM Session
WHERE
(ModuleId = ?)
ORDER BY SessionDate, SessionTime 
";

$sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['modules']);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

$sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionName,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbModuleId);

$sessionqrystmt->store_result();

$sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();   

if($sessionnum ==0){
echo "<p>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</p>";
} else { 

$sessionHTML = '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
$sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           

while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {
    $sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s - %s - %s</option>", $dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, $dbSessionDate, $dbSessionTime) . PHP_EOL;  
}

$sessionHTML .= '</select>';

$assessmentform = "<form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post' onsubmit='return sessionvalidation();'>
<p>Assessments: {$sessionHTML} </p>
<p><input id='sessionSubmit' type='submit' value='Submit Assessment' name='sessionSubmit' /></p>  
<div id='sessionAlert'></div>    
</form>";

echo $assessmentform;

}

}

if (isset($_POST['sessionSubmit'])) {   

$currentsession = "form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post'>
<p>Current Assessment's Date/Start Time:</p>
<p>Assessment: <input type='text' id='currentAssessment' name='Assessmentcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='{$dbSessionName}'/> </p> //Line 243
<p>Date: <input type='text' id='currentDate' name='Datecurrent' readonly='readonly' value='{$dbSessionDate}'/> </p> //Line 244
<p>Start Time: <input type='text' id='currentTime' name='Timecurrent' readonly='readonly' value='{$dbSessionTime}'/> </p> //Line 245
</form>
";  

echo $currentsession;

    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Could the code below do it:

```
if (isset($_POST['sessionSubmit'])) {

    $sessionquery = "
    SELECT SessionId, SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId
    FROM Session
    WHERE
    (ModuleId = ?)
    ORDER BY SessionDate, SessionTime 
    ";

    $sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['modules']);
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

    $sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

    $sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionName,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbModuleId);

    $sessionqrystmt->store_result();

$currentsession = "<form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post'>
<p>Current Assessment's Date/Start Time:</p>
<p>Assessment: <input type='text' id='currentAssessment' name='Assessmentcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='{$dbSessionName}'/> </p>
<p>Date: <input type='text' id='currentDate' name='Datecurrent' readonly='readonly' value='{$dbSessionDate}'/> </p>
<p>Start Time: <input type='text' id='currentTime' name='Timecurrent' readonly='readonly' value='{$dbSessionTime}'/> </p>
<input type='hidden' id='hiddenId' name='hiddenAssessment' value='{$dbSessionId}'/>
</form>
";  

echo $currentsession;

    }
```

Do I need the store_result(); in this situation?

Comment: @Jack Maney Where do you see an SQL injection vulnerability?

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually using the posted value of `session` to retrieve the selected session from the database.

The sql you are showing, is used to generate the `select` box and to get the selected `session` in a posted form, you would need to add another database call in the

```
if (isset($_POST['sessionSubmit'])) {
  ...
}
```

section to get the previously selected session using `$_POST['session']`, probably something like:

```
$sessionquery = "
SELECT SessionId, SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId
FROM Session
WHERE
(SessionId = ?)
";
....
$sessionqrystmt->bind_param("i",$_POST['session']);    // assuming the session ID is an integer
```

Comment: I have not tested the code but I included an update in the question, could the code in the update work? I thought I will have your view on it before testing it, just to ensure that I understood your answer

Comment: @user1789716 Sorry, I did not read the code correctly, the select box is already in the form...

Comment: @user1789716 Your edit looks like it should do the job, although I am not that familiar with mysqli (I prefer PDO).

Comment: Yeah I prefer PDO but havn't got the correct vesion in order to use PDO. I will test this code and come back to you on the outcome

Comment: I tested the code, I am getting no errors but nothing is being displayed in the text inputs. Plus for some strange reason this is being outputted `form action='/u00000000/Asses_app/editsession.php' method='post'> `

Comment: @user1789716 It seems your html is not correct, you are for example missing the opening `<` for your form element: `$currentsession = "form action= ...`

Comment: I will get back to you on this. Just need to complete something first before testing this

Comment: Ok I have tested it but nothing is being displayed in the textboxes. But you did sort out the missing < issue. I just need the values selected from the session drop down menu to be displayed in their relevant textboxes in the `$currentsession` varialbe. Code above under the UPDATE is updated